# Using AWS ElasticSearch in a Rails App on AWS Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to switch my Rails Beanstalk app to use AWS ElasticSearch in place of an EC2 instance running ElasticSearch. My app uses the [serachkick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick) gem.

Requests from the Rails app seem to get blocked when trying to reach the ES service. I modified the access policies for the ES service to allow for specific IPs and running `curl -XGET $ELASTICSEARCH_URL` returns the expected result:

```
{
    "status" : 200,
    "name" : "Man-Killer",
    "cluster_name" : "085567994644:curatiopv2",
    "version" : {
    "number" : "1.5.2",
    "build_hash" : "62ff9868b4c8a0c45860bebb259e21980778ab1c",
    "build_timestamp" : "2015-04-27T09:21:06Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.4"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

However, when trying to create an object through the rails app that needs to be indexed by ElasticSearch, I get a `Faraday::TimeoutError: execution expired` error that - looking back at the logs - points me to this line:

`from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.13/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:21:in block in perform_request'`

which makes me believe the connection to ElasticSearch does not go through from the rails application.

Anyone with an experience on how to combine AWS ES with Rails on BeanStalk who could shed some light on the problem I am facing?

thanks!

Comment: it turned out I needed to have `http` included at the beginning of the `ELATICSEARCH_URL`